# Trying to pull a word out of a string, in google script, on google sheets. Not familiar with the language, cant make the functions work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm a vanilla C guy, and just having trouble wrapping my head around google script, in a google sheets project. I want to copy/paste a blob of text into cell(1, 1), press a button, then pull data out of that string and turn it into a pretty table. Just having trouble parsing the string...
My thought is to search for the word "DUG", then give me the word after it.

The format of the blob is: 
garbage garbage DUG Username garbage garbage DUG Usernumber garbage garbage DUG Username garbage garbage DUG Usernumber (etc etc).

The problem: I can locate the first instance of the word DUG, but I can't seem to chop the string at that location. I've heard to use left(), right(), or mid(), but it's saying those functions don't exist. It seems like I'm missing something easy. Any tips for a noob?
Thank you so much!

```
// function runs when button is clicked
function SortCustomerList() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = spreadsheet.getName();

  var pastedDataRange = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1);                // location of the pasted data
  var pastedData = pastedDataRange.getValue();                     //     get the data from that cell
  var pastedText = pastedData.toString();                          //     convert that data into a string

  // returns an index location of where "DUG" starts in the string
  var foundLoc = pastedText.indexOf("DUG");                        


  // show me that location for testing (number. int?) ***works!!***
  spreadsheet.getRange(4, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(foundLoc);                 





  // i want to chop the string at "DUG", show me everything to the right, starting where you found "DUG"
  // ****doesnt work. returns the entire paste, not chopped
  spreadsheet.getRange(10, 1).activate();            
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(pastedText.split(foundLoc));        







  // future:  rather than the rest of the string, just give me the word after "DUG"
  //          set index (foundLoc) to AFTER the "DUG Username", to find the next instance of "DUG"
  //          loop it, until there are no more instances of the word "DUG"
  //          put it into pretty rows and columns



  spreadsheet.getRange(5, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Test Ran!');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the tool i needed is substring(). just replace split() with substring() and it "just works". thank you to the friend who helped, and thank you all for the help ive looked up over the years. cheers!